# Android Studio - " Unfortunately 'appname' has stopped working "

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I am making my first material design based app by following a [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) . I encountered several errors but have overcome those except the app crashing error. I have no idea why is this happening.I tried using both API 21 and API 22 SDKs as well as the AVD. I tried in real device too.I suppose the error should be with the java file but have no idea in which file, where and why. I am doing this for my college submission.Please Help me with this.

My MainActivity.java :

```
package com.aa.bb.cc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My Activity_Main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My toolbar.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

My styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">


    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>


   </style>
</resources>
```

LogCat :

```
    --------- beginning of crash
06-03 11:24:46.739    2065-2065/com.ij.indrajith.firstmaterialdesignapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ij.indrajith.firstmaterialdesignapp, PID: 2065
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ij.indrajith.firstmaterialdesignapp/com.ij.indrajith.firstmaterialdesignapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:360)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.ij.indrajith.firstmaterialdesignapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

By seeing the logcat, i tried changing the parent theme to many other themes but of no use.

Update:
I did some changes with the theme and now the error jumps to :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ij.indrajith.firstmaterialdesignapp/com.ij.indrajith.firstmaterialdesignapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Comment: Can you provide error codes from logcat? To do this, connect the device via ADB, and run the project on Android Studio. When app crashes, log will be created within the Studio. Edit the post with error logs, if you can.

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović . I have updated the post with logcat. Please look into it and help me find a solution

Comment: If you look at the log, it says "... AppCompat does not support the current theme features". That's where your error is. If you're designing for 21 SDK level, there's no need to use AppCompat libraries, they are used to implement Material Design into Android versions that don't support it natively.

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović yeah i saw that too and tried changing the base class theme to themes like app 'Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar' , 'Theme.AppCompat.Light' etc.. But it didn't help. Can you please tell me is there any other way or a specific way in the same approach to overcome the problem?

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović In that case, how to take care of the backward compatability of the app? Also, when the older API dont support material design, how to design it to support material design in API 21,22 and also work fine in older APIs?

Comment: Well, i made some changes and the error jumps to this : ' java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ij.indrajith.firstmaterialdesignapp/com.ij.indrajith.firstmaterialdesignapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar'

Answer (score 1):

In your layout you are using:

```
android.widget.Toolbar
```

In your Activity you are using:

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Change your layout in:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
  .... />
```